# How to learn how humans behave?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning

I have decided to study psychology as a hobby. I want it to understand better people that I am interacting with. Specifically, I want to know:

- Why humans talk / behave in certain ways?
- How they think and why they think in those ways?
- How do people make decisions?
- How to study personality as a whole?

What areas of psychology should I study? I have heard that an OCEAN model can help me with that. Will it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those research questions are broad and therefore don't point specifically to sub-areas in psychology. For example, you could examine behavior in multiple species (flies, rats, humans), multiple contexts (social media, laboratory, financial markets), and diverse methods (neuroscience, surveys, computational modeling). However, your mention of personality suggests that one area to look closely at would be Social and Personality Psychology, which are two domains often combined: http://spsp.org/about/what-socialpersonality-psychology.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try. I know that my question wasn't "professional," but that's the reason I was asking :)

Comment: great, hope it was useful. You might also look at Cognitive Psychology, which also has a long history of studying behavior.